# File attachment using virtual path in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an asp.net project which has a form with a file attachment capability. Since I'm uploading the form on a server, I can't use a physical path. How do I use the asp:FileUpload with a virtual path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a virtual path to a physical path:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Example.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have this quite right.  The file upload control will POST the file data to your server, and it can be accessed using the PostedFile property of the control.

You then save this file (I assume) to a physical path on your server (which you can access).